# $n + 1$ Automorphisms being linearly dependent.

Tags: field-theory

I have $G = \{\sigma_1, ..., \sigma_n\}$ a subgroup of automorphisms of a field $K$ and $F$ the fixed field of $G.$ Suppose now that $n < [K:F].$ It follows that there are more than $n$ $F-$linearly independent elements of $K: \alpha_1, ..., \alpha_{n + 1}.$ Why is it that for any $i, \sigma_i(\alpha_1)x_1 + \sigma_i(\alpha_2)x_2 + ... + \sigma_i(\alpha_{n + 1})x_{n + 1} = 0$ has a non trivial solution $x_i = \beta_i$ where $\beta_i$ not all zero?

Comment: If we apply $\sigma_i^{-1}$, we obtain a linear dependence among the $\alpha_j$, don't we?

Comment: Applying $\sigma_i^{-1}$ gives us $\alpha_1 \sigma_i^{-1}(x_1) + ... + \alpha_{n + 1} \sigma_i^{-1}(x_{n + 1}) = 0.$ My book says there is a nontrivial solution to this. How do we know that?